# How can I apply Searching in a drive(folder to folder)?

Tags: c#

I am making a simple antivirus. So I have to search file in the a specific drive. How can I scan the files in drive in each folder.
 i try this

```
Directory.GetFiles("E:\folder","*.*,SerachOption.AllDirectories);
```

by using this O am able to find the file in the folders of selected folder. But I cannot select the drive and apply search in the drive. Any one help me out

Comment: see my latest update, by this you can get the file list of a drive

Answer (score 0):

Make `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` and use this way

```
var fileList = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\").GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

and then you can iterate over this

```
foreach (var fileInfo in fileList)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.ToString());
   }
```

Comment: I want to select the drive (Like C,D,E) not the folder.

Comment: isn't my solution select the drive ? I have show using the `E` drive, isn't it working ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a FolderBrowserDialog to show a directory selection window. With this, the user can choose the root folder where the search should start.

Then you can use Directory.GetFiles as you already did, with the path coming from the FolderBrowserDialog.

Quick example of code:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/folderbrowserdialog

Comment: sharing link is not a good answer, show some code example for solution